# Facebook IOS SDK Login works on simulator, not on device

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

Facebook Login, got myself into a bit of a spot.

Unfortunately for the job I am doing I only have access to Snow Leopard running xcode 3.2.6 and cannot alter from that. Blast from the past I know.

To get facebook login working using FB SDK 3.0 I used:

AppDelegate.h:

```
     #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
....
    @property (retain, nonatomic) FBSession *session;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize session = _session;
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation { 
     return [self.session handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Then in my FBLoginViewController.m viewDidLoad:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate;
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

   if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
       appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init]; 

       if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
         [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                       FBSessionState status, 
                                                              NSError *error) {
                }];
            }
      }
```

Now this worked on the simulator 4.3. I think confirming I have the fb App Id set correctly in the plist, the app set up correctly etc.

However when testing on a device with IOS 6 it crashes with relevant sections of crash log saying:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSYS)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                       0x000e7cac 0x59000 + 584876
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34a384b4 0x34a37000 + 5300
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34a39836 0x34a37000 + 10294
3   MyApp                       0x000e7ca0 0x59000 + 584864
4   MyApp                           0x000d9d08 0x59000 + 527624
5   MyApp                           0x000d9934 0x59000 + 526644
6   MyApp                           0x000da6c6 0x59000 + 530118
7   MyApp                           0x0005b1f0 0x59000 + 8688
8   MyApp                           0x000660a4 0x59000 + 53412
9   UIKit                           0x336130a0 0x33525000 + 975008
10  UIKit                           0x33613052 0x33525000 + 974930
11  UIKit                           0x33613030 0x33525000 + 974896
12  UIKit                           0x336128e6 0x33525000 + 973030
13  UIKit                           0x33612ddc 0x33525000 + 974300
14  UIKit                           0x3353b5ec 0x33525000 + 91628
15  UIKit                           0x335287fc 0x33525000 + 14332
16  UIKit                           0x33528116 0x33525000 + 12566
17  GraphicsServices                0x382ab5a0 0x382a5000 + 26016
18  GraphicsServices                0x382ab1ce 0x382a5000 + 25038
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3331c170 0x33285000 + 618864
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3331c112 0x33285000 + 618770
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3331af94 0x33285000 + 614292
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3328deb8 0x33285000 + 36536
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3328dd44 0x33285000 + 36164
24  GraphicsServices                0x382aa2e6 0x382a5000 + 21222
25  UIKit                           0x3357c2f4 0x33525000 + 357108
26  MyApp                       0x0005b012 0x59000 + 8210
27  MyApp                       0x0005afc8 0x59000 + 8136
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x0000004e    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3b091bd0    r5: 0x2fda7c0c      r6: 0x1cd560e0      r7: 0x2fda6734
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x2fda6764     r10: 0x1cd560e0     r11: 0x1cdac4d0
    ip: 0x000e7c0d    sp: 0x2fda672c      lr: 0x34a384b7      pc: 0x000e7cac
  cpsr: 0x60000010
```

What I have tried:

Now obviously with xcode 3.2.6 I cannot run via xcode and access the console for further debugging on my IOS 6 device. So I sent the project to a friend (without paid account so can't test on device) who confirmed it worked on xcode 4.5 and with simulator 6.

So if it works on the simulator 6 and 4.3 why would it not work on IOS 6 device? I am a little stumped....

After playing around (just commenting lines out etc) I think it is crashing at this line:

```
appdelagate.session = [[FBSession aloc] init];
```

But am finding it hard to be sure or have any idea why.

Would love some ideas or help,
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're under equipped to be an iOS developer... buy OSX Lion to develop for iOS 6.

Comment: Tell me about it. Let me explain, I do have a newish MacBook pro at home that I usually use, however I was posted to work for 3 months in Outback Australia, about 12 hours from home and didn't bring it. Big mistake. Anyway got asked if I would whip up a program and managed to get access to a Mac that has hardware that can only run snow leopard. I only need to be able to test on device until I can get home. There must be a way of getting this working, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was to upgrade to xcode 4.2 for snow leopard. I didn't realise xcode 4.2 was an option for snow leopard. However it is. The code above worked immediately with no changes in xcode 4.2.